# How to mix jQuery and a UiInstance for generating GUIs

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a fairly basic dialog form worked out using the GUI builder. However I would like to put a slider widget in the form. (don't ask!)

The jQuery UI lib has a slider, but it seems that in order to get all the jQuery scripts and css loaded into the template, I have to switch to the HTML service instead of UI service for page generation.

At the moment I have my Gui builder form working ok, running something like this;

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("DocEditorGui"));
  return app;
}
```

and I have a jQuery slider in a html page that I can pull in like this;

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mySliderWidget');
}
```

However using an HTML file seems to be incompatible with the app.createHTML() HTML type widget, in that nothing is displayed if I pass the HTMLoutput contents. The HTML is definitely processed, as Logger.log shows the correct jQuery and html.

```js
var t =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mySliderWidget'); 
var widgetHTML = container.createHTML(t.getContent());
widgetHTML.setStyleAttribute("background", "green");
Logger.log( t.getContent()  );
vPanel.add(widgetHTML );
```

However presumably this is getting caught by caja also, because the effect appears to be stripping out all of the id tags for jQuery. The HTML is added, its all broken for jQuery.

Is there an example for this use-case, or am I way too early to be trying things like this?

As an test-case, this jQUery slider example;
http://pastebin.com/bnY7PhCL

runs in the caja playground here;
http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaPlayground

but does not run under HTML widget as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.createHTML does not use Caja. It strips out all HTML except a small subset. You can see in the docs here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_html

that it strips out all script tags.

HtmlService is not the app.createHTML widget; it is an entirely new API and requires you to build the entire app that way. There's no way to mix and match HtmlService's support for jQuery with UiApp; it's one or the other.

Comment: Is there any scope for the reverse, i.e. to pull the app-scripts widgets into the HTML service. For example id like to display a Chart, but the examples are all UiApp based.

Comment: There is not. However, chart support for HtmlService is on the near-term roadmap.

Comment: I guess a cool thing would be to support gadgets in UiApps and html service, because its more generic. In fact it would be handy if gadgets were supported in docs Documents as well, because then there would be scope to insert arbitrary charts and representations such as R-statistics charts, and Chemical structural diagrams into docs. I like MathJax for equations, and I could wrap one of them up nice, and use it for typesetting big equations...